# Expand selection based on cell value and split the expanded selection into a separate file

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling with this for a while now.

A1:O7 are frozen columns.
Only the Column A contains trigger values that I find using

```
Dim Cell As Range
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:="BANK:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
```

After that I need to expand the selection so that all the rows and the columns to the right and down from the cell found until the next cell to be found are copied and split into a separate file along with the frozen columns A1:O7 at the top. The range is A7:Oxxxx. There is no data beyond the O column.

Is there a solution to this without using any Excel add-ons?

Comment: Is your 'Bank' criteria to be found unique? Can you better explain what "next cell to be found" in this string "from the cell found until the next cell to be found" does mean? Should we understand that there are more "Bank:" strings and you need the slice between two consecutive such cells, including all columns for that specific area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand the task. There are some information missing so this solution might not exactly fitting your needs. I hope it will work for you.

```
Private Sub Bank()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank") 'change according to your workingsheet
    
    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Set rngHeader = ws.Range("A1:O7")
    Dim iWidth As Integer 'Data and header width
    iWidth = rngHeader.Columns.Count
    
    Dim strSearchText As String
    strSearchText = "BANK:"
    Dim rngSearchArea As Range
    Set rngSearchArea = ws.Range(Range("A7"), ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A:A").Cells.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    Dim strFirstFound As String
    Dim rngCurrentFound As Range
    Set rngCurrentFound = ws.Range("A7")
    Set rngCurrentFound = rngSearchArea.Find(What:=strSearchText, After:=rngCurrentFound, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If rngCurrentFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strFirstFound = rngCurrentFound.Address
    
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngNextFound As Range
    
    Do
         'Get the position of the next occurence to set the end position
         Set rngNextFound = rngSearchArea.FindNext(rngCurrentFound)
         If rngNextFound.Row > rngCurrentFound.Row Then
         'There is next one
            Set rngSource = Range(rngCurrentFound, rngNextFound.Offset(-1)).Resize(, iWidth)
        Else
        'It was the last one
            'If there are data in column A below the last BANK: use the next line
            'Set rngSource = ws.Range(rngCurrentFound, Cells(ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A:A").Cells.Count).End(xlUp), iWidth))
            'Use this one to select until the last used cell in the worksheet
            Set rngSource = ws.Range(rngCurrentFound, ws.UsedRange.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Cells.Count))
        End If
        'rngSource.Select
        Call Bankcopy(rngSource, rngHeader)
        Set rngCurrentFound = rngSearchArea.FindNext(rngCurrentFound)
        
    Loop While rngCurrentFound.Address <> strFirstFound
End Sub

Private Sub Bankcopy(rngSource As Range, ByVal rngHeader As Range)
    'Create new book and copy headers
    Dim wbNewBook As Workbook
    Set wbNewBook = Workbooks.Add()
    Dim wsNewSheet As Worksheet
    Set wsNewSheet = wbNewBook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    'Copy header
    Set rngTarget = wsNewSheet.Range("A1")  'To header left upper
    rngHeader.Copy
    rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Copy data
    Set rngTarget = wsNewSheet.Range("A8")  'Data left upper
    rngSource.Copy
    rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'MsgBox "Test Stop"
    'wbNewBook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a god. There were some issues, but I adapted your code and it works nicely up until the part where I need to save the new workbooks. I tried using  both ThisWorkbook.SaveAs and Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs withing the Bankcopy sub, but neither of them work -- 'run-time error 1004 saveas method of workbook class failed' appears.

Comment: You would like to save the new workbook. We can use the wbNewBook for this reason. So try:  wbNewBook.SaveAs.

Comment: Yup, I did try it too, getting the same Run-time error 1004 "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed. This is what I used  SaveName = wbNewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value wbNewBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Downloads\" & SaveName, FileFormat:=xls, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: The FileFormat is wrong.   See: [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).   Use: `wbNewBook.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\User\Downloads\" & SaveName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault, CreateBackup:=False`. I hope it will work.

Comment: Such a rookie mistake, thanks for pointing it out. It does actually work now!